# How to calculate the relation strength between 2 nodes?

Tags: c#, dictionary, graph, breadth-first-search

So I'm trying to make an application that resembles the six degrees of Kevin Bacon game. First I read from a text file the contains the actors and the movies they starred in. The format of it is something like that :[image]

So I stored my graph as an adjacency list that takes actors as nodes and their neighbors and which movies they starred (i.e Dictionary < string, HashSet < Dictionary < string, HashSet < string >>>>) (i.e Actor A: Actor B movie 0, movie 1, movie 7, Actor C movie 8 Actor Z movie 9... etc ) I know the data structure is weird but I was asked to do it like that. This is my graph class.

```
class Graph
{
    public Dictionary<string, HashSet<Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>> dic;
    public Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> dic1;

    int count = 0;


    public Graph()
    {
        dic = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>>();
        //dic2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
    }
    public Graph(string filename, string delimeter)
    {
        dic = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>>();
        //dic2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);


        while (sr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            char r;
            r = Convert.ToChar(delimeter);
            int j;
            int i=0;

            string[] names = line.Split(r);
            for (j=1; j < names.Length; j++)
            {
                for (i = j; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!dic.ContainsKey(names[i])) //without this line code throws  exception key is not found
                        addVertex(names[i]);
                    if (!(dic[names[i]].Equals(dic[names[j]])))

                        addEdge(names[i], names[j], names[0]);


                }

            }




        }

        sr.Close();
    }

    public void addEdge(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        if (!dic.ContainsKey(a))
        {
            addVertex(a);
        }

        if (!dic.ContainsKey(b))
        {
            addVertex(b);
        }


        dic1 = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

        dic1.Add(a, new HashSet<string>());

        dic1.Add(b, new HashSet<string>());

        dic1[b].Add(c);
        dic1[a].Add(c);

        dic[a].Add(dic1);
        dic[b].Add(dic1);



    }

    public void addVertex(string v)
    {
        if (!dic.ContainsKey(v))
            dic.Add(v, new HashSet<Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>());
    }


    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>> adjacentto(string v)
    {
        return dic[v];
    }
}
```

And then I'm supposed to calculate the degree of separation between each 2 nodes for which I applied the BFS algorithm. This is my BFS class:

```
     class BFS
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> dist = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    //private Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>> prev = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>>();


    public void BFSDegree(Graph g, string s, string p)
    {
        Queue<string> q = new Queue<string>();

        dist.Add(s, 0);
        q.Enqueue(s);
        //int count;

        //int v = 0;
        while (q.Count() != 0)
        {
            string j = q.Dequeue();
            //count = 0;
            foreach (Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> h in g.adjacentto(j))
            {
                foreach (string m in h.Keys)
                {

                    if (!dist.ContainsKey(m))
                    {
                        q.Enqueue(m);
                        dist.Add(m, 1 + dist[j]);



                    }
                    if (j == p)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("             " + dist[j]);
                        //count++;
                        return;
                    }

                }


            }


        }


    }






    public void BfsOnFile(string filename, string delimeter, Graph G)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string actor1 = "";
        string actor2 = "";
        while (sr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();

            char r;
            r = Convert.ToChar(delimeter);
            string[] names = line.Split(r);
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {

                actor1 = names[0];
                actor2 = names[1];


            }
            Console.Write(" " + line);
            BFSDegree(G, actor1, actor2);

            dist.Clear();


        }


    }

}
```

And through these 2 classes I was able to calculate the degree of separation between them. Now my problem is to calculate something called the relation strength between 2 nodes. for example Actor A and actor B are directly linked with a degree of separation equal 1. The relation strength between them is three movies since they directly appeared together in the three movies.
Actor C and actor E are linked with a degree of separation equal 2 through either actor A, actor B or actor D. The relation strength should equal the max of the three options. So from what I understand if I should calculate the relation strength between actor A and actor B, and since they starred in 3 movies together I should go the dictionary of key A that contains the dictionary of key B and count the number of movies in its hashset. But I don't know how? like the data structure is too complex to deal with but unfortunately I was asked to do it like that!